# MySQLi Insert() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I cannot get my insert function working. I have used this frame work.

https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

The error i get is

**Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /home/hghdigib/public_html/backup/feed/classes/xml_upload.php on line 39**

I have stripped lost out to make it easier to follow.

Any help would be much appreciated been scratching my head for a while.

My Global Class File

```
require_once("classes/database.php");
require_once("classes/xml_upload.php");
$db = new Mysqlidb('localhost', '', '', '');
$dataupload = new DataUpload($db);
$dataupload->getAllProducts($db);
```

My xml_upload.php class

```
class DataUpload {

    public $db;
    public $xml_upload;

    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }   

    public function getAllProducts() {
        foreach ($propertys as $results)
        {
            $insertData = array(
                'prop_id' => $results['prop_id'],
                'lastchanged' => $results['lastchanged'],
                'url' => $results['url']
            );

            if($db->insert('propertie_ids', $insertData)) echo 'success!';
        }

    }       

}
```

Comment: Remember that PHP has **no** automatic scope as for example in Java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($db->insert('propertie_ids', $insertData)) echo 'success!';
```

Use `$this->db` instread of `$db`. You must refer to `$this` if you want to access class members.

```
$this->db->insert('propertie_ids', $insertData)
```

Comment: OMFG, Thanks dude, been going mad haha. Thanks

Comment: Why was I marked down?

Comment: @BrentFrench Glad I could help! If it worked for you, always check the big outlined V left to the correct answer ;) I don't know who marked you down or why.